# How can you trigger an even when clicking on a bootstrap button without an id?

Tags: javascript

For a javascript project, I need to be able to interact with three bootstrap buttons.

The code for the buttons goes as follows:

```html
<a data-id="0" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
<a data-id="1" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
<a data-id="2" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
```

I am **not** allowed to modify this line, so simply adding an id to the button is out of the question.
That being said, how can I add an click listener to these buttons and interact with them?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you at least try searching `how to select element without id javascript` on google ? Please make the MINIMUM amount of research before posting questions like these.

Comment: Hint for your research: `CSS selectors` ... alternative _ID_ could be `data-id` (at least its values seem unique). If you already tried something, please post your code as [example] (even if it's based on non-present `id` or not working). We value each efforts!

Comment: @MihaiT I did. Somehow nothing came up that dealt with bootstrap buttons the way i needed it to.

Comment: YOu should know that one of the most important part of developing is knowing how to ' ask google ' and find your solutions. 99% of the problems you encounter have been asked before by someone somewhere ( most of the time here on SO ) . When you google `how to select element without id javascript` first 2 results are from SO which would've helped you enough to solve your problem. So i don't know why you say ' nothing came up '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the classname:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

var myFunction = function() {
  console.log("Button with data-id", this.getAttribute("data-id"), "clicked");
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<a data-id="0" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a> <a data-id="1" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a> <a data-id="2" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
```

Comment: I ended up using the classname as you suggesting along with the querySelector suggested by zero298 and it worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use querySelector, see example below:

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector('[data-id="0"]')
var button2 = document.querySelector('[data-id="1"]')
var button3 = document.querySelector('[data-id="2"]')

button1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("button1");
});

button2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("button2");
});

button3.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("button3");
});
```

```html
<a data-id="0" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a> <a data-id="1" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a> <a data-id="2" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

They already seem to *have* ids that you can query for using `querySelector` along with attribute selectors.

```js
document.querySelector("a[data-id='0']").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("You clicked data id 0");
});
```

```html
<a data-id="0" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
<a data-id="1" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
<a data-id="2" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **data-id** as selector.

see example

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('[data-id="0"]');

console.log(elem)

elem.click();
```

```html
<a data-id="0" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
<a data-id="1" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
<a data-id="2" class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-add" href="#">Buy</a>
```